# TFS Build 2010 - Custom Binary Location and SharePoint WSP

Tags: sharepoint, msbuild, wsp

I'm building a solution using TFS Build 2010. This solution has multiple projects and one of the projects is SharePoint.

I want TFS Build to put binaries for each project in its own folder (i.e. customized binary folder). So I followed [the instructions from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff977206.aspx) and it works.

Now the challenge is that I'm **not** able to generate a WSP file with the customized binary folder (note that I'm able to generate WSP *without* the customized binary folder). I'm getting this error:

```
C:\\..\..\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets (389): Unable to get the assembly for SharePoint Project Item "Layouts".
```

I think TFS Build/MSbuild is not able to locate the correct assembly because I changed the "OutputPath" value to achieve customized binary folders.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you need to change the binary location of the projects? What would be wrong with leaving the default locations?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to update the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets` file. This file is located in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\` on the build server.

Go to line number 366: `<CreateSharePointProjectService Configuration=...`

Change the attribute `OutDir="$(TeamBuildOutDir)"` to `OutDir="$(TargetDir)"` and save the file.

I have a blog [post](http://blogs.like10.com/2011/08/04/team-build-2010-customized-output-directories-sharepoint-2010-wsps/) on this topic with screenshots.

Comment: I have the same issue that the OP states.  I followed your guidelines here and on your blog post.  I'm still not getting this to work.  My error is now:  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets (411): Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.PathUtils.HasIllegalDeploymentPathCharacters(System.String)'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please refer to the following [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755609/tfs-2010-building-sharepoint-2010-solution-with-custom-outputs)